# Azure Traffic Manager and its End Points' Poll Status Degraded

Tags: azure

I have a traffic manager with 6 End Points. Although I can access the application via the traffic manager and the individual end points URLs, **I dont know why the status on them is being shown as "*Degraded*".**

All the 6 End Points are showing *Degraded* and so the traffic manager status is also showing as Degraded. The app is in production and people are using it and haven't complained about the accesibility.

I am not sure why the status us *Degraded*. These are Https end points and the same has been configured in the "*Configure*" tab and also in the service definition file.

Any pointers? I have seen a few such queries on the forums, but none of them meet my condition.

Comment: There is information regarding this issue in this article: https://www.amido.com/code/azure-traffic-manager-the-curious-case-of-the-degraded-cluster/

Answer (score 2):

Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/06/troubleshooting-scenario-4-windows-azure-traffic-manager-degraded-status.aspx for how to troubleshoot this.  Essentially, your WATM probe path is returning something besides a 200 (ie. a 301 redirect).